# Delete and update a row in gridview having value of multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview, gridcontrol

I want to delete and update a row in Gridview but that grid have values of two tables

I'm using following query for selecting-

```
SELECT JobMaster.Country, JobMaster.City, JobMaster.State, JobMaster.EmploymentType, 
JobMaster.JobTitle, JobMaster.SpecializedArea, JobMaster.Specializedskill, JobMaster.ID, 
JobMaster.[Post Assign], RAssign.RecruiterID AS Post_Assign FROM JobMaster 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RAssign 
ON JobMaster.ID = RAssign.JobID 
WHERE (RAssign.RecruiterID = @RecruiterID) OR (@RecruiterID IS NULL)
```

What statement should I use for Update,Insert and for delete?
(Actually I'm new in coding and I just know to delete from single table but in above statement we are selecting to tables data one is "Jobmaster" and second is "RAssign".
Please help me if possible)